# How to view bash tokens?

Tags: bash

Is there a utility that displays how Bash *would* tokenize a given line of input?

For example:

```
$ get_tokens '(echo hello;) 2> /dev/null'
'(' 
'echo'
'hello'
';'
')'
'2>'
'/dev/null'
```

Note: I did the above to the best of my knowledge, but if it is incorrect, I apologize. It is used purely as an example.

Comment: Why is this needed? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @Inian For educational purposes.

Comment: Great! I suggest don’t reinvent the wheel, look at the source code to see how the command line is tokenised.

Comment: @Inian I feel like it would be worthwhile to have a utility hat does this, that doesn’t require reading the source code. Yes, reading the source code will tell you exactly how executables are searched, but type is still a very useful command (and particularly for beginners, because it shows some aspect of “absolute truth” that is understandable, but whose reasons and underlying implementation may be complex). I am also very lazy, and will look for a cheap solution over anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [bash debugger](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/bashdb.html) has what you need?